# Android: Alertbuilder change color on runtime

Tags: android, colors, runtime, alert

I got one Alretdialog with an EditText and a Seekbar. By using the Seekbar, i want to change the background color of my edittext.
Changing the seekbar color works, but not changing the edittext background color.

```
    EditText newSubjectEdit;
    SeekBar colorSeeker;
    Builder subjectAlert;
    LinearLayout lg;
private Builder getNewSubjectAlert() {
            subjectAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            lg = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            ...

            newSubjectEdit = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            ...
            lg.addView(newSubjectEdit);

            colorSeeker = new SeekBar(getApplicationContext());
colorSeeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
            ...
            lg.addView(colorSeeker);

            subjectAlert.setView(lg);        
            // set ok and cancel ...
```

the listener:

```
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                seekBar.setBackgroundColor(color);  // works !!
                newSubjectEdit.setBackgroundColor(color);  // doesn't work
            }
        };
```

hope you understand what i mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifound prob.as you have add view dynamicalle.newSubjectEdit called more than once.so it is overridden.and for seekbar seekbar.OnSeekBarChangeListener gives you seekbar as arg. which is referenced.so it gives correct object

Comment: finally I got it. Most important was, that I declared newsubjectEdit as final ...